# Create mimetic::MimeEntity from std::string email from POP3 Account

Tags: c++, libcurl, pop3

I'm currently trying to read some mails from a POP3 Gmail Account and I used libCurl library for this task. I created a **std::list m_mailsInbox** which stores the index for each email inside this account.

As you can see, I'm fetching inside this list using the mentioned index and I read every mail which I stored inside a **std::string dataEmail**. Inside this variable I have the header and the body of the mail, and what I need is to create a **MimeEntity** object using mimetic library.

This is my current code:

```
void MailServer::ReadMails(char *username,char *password)
{
    //fetchs into the list one by one
    for(std::list<MailInbox>::iterator it = m_mailsInbox.begin(); it != m_mailsInbox.end(); ++it)   
    {
        struct MemoryStruct chunkMail;
        chunkMail.memory = (char*) malloc(1);  //it will grow as necessary
        chunkMail.size = 0;    //there's no data at this point

        curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_USERNAME,username);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_PASSWORD,password);

        m_popsAccount = "pop3s://pop.gmail.com:995/" + it->index;   //creates the URL for the email it->index (i.e: 1)

        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, m_popsAccount.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 

        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunkMail);
        //some servers needs this validation
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

        res = curl_easy_perform(handle); 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        else //everything was fine
        {
            printf("%s\n",chunkMail.memory); //here is the information of the email

            if(ReadMailHeader(chunkMail.memory))
            {
                std::string dataEmail = chunkMail.memory;
                //if returns true, the mail must be saved
                MimeEntity mime; 
                //how i create this object using dataEmail string??                 
            }           
        }

        //frees the data inside
        if(chunkMail.memory)
            free(chunkMail.memory);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ugh; manual memory management. http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks

Answer (score 0):

```
                std::istringstream ss(std::string(chunkMail.memory,m_mailsInbox.at(i).size));

                ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);   

                //si la funcion retorno true, entonces hay que guardar los datos
                MimeEntity me(ss);
```

this is enough for doing it! :)